# false implication (A => B) = 0

Tags: logic

this is a question about logical implication.

I need to prove that the implication $X \Rightarrow Y$ is verified. I use a proof by contrapositive, that is, I assume $Y = 0$ and I want to prove $X = 0$.

Now $Y$ itself is an implication, let say $Y := (A \Rightarrow B)$. My assumption is then translated into $ (A \Rightarrow B) = 0 $. My question now is the following.

Saying that $ (A \Rightarrow B) = 0 $ is equivalent to assume $(A=1) \Rightarrow (B=0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. $(A\Rightarrow B)=0$ is equivalent to "$A=1$ *and* $B=0$", or, if you will, $A(1-B)=1$.